# ¿Como hago para hacer desaparecer el VídeoView de la vista del usuario cuando el vídeo acaba?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

> Reproduzco el vídeo en streaming cuando pulso el ImagenButton de la imagen pero cuando acaba el vídeo no desaparece, como puedo hacerlo desaparecer para volver a ver la imagen que hay debajo del vídeo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Código:

```
 private void streamVideo() {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    vv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mdialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    mdialog.setMessage("Cargando video, espere.....");
    mdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mdialog.show();

    try {
        if (!vv.isPlaying()) {
            MediaController mdc = new MediaController(this);
            mdc.setAnchorView(vv);
            vv.setMediaController(mdc);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://s3.amazonaws.com/fancyfootageclips/website/vid/2015-02-02-concert.mp4");
            vv.setVideoURI(uri);
            vv.requestFocus();
            vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mdialog.dismiss();
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                    vv.start();
                }
            });
        } else {
            vv.stopPlayback();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getCause();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para determinar cuando termino la reproducción de un video en un **MediaPlayer** se usa el listener [**OnCompletionListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html), por lo tanto cuando termina puedes cambiar la visibilidad del mismo:

```
vv.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                //Desaparece VideoView al terminar la reproducción.
                vv.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }
            });
```

En el sitio puedes ver varios ejemplos del uso de [OnCompletionListener](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+OnCompletionListener)